# Is it possible to directly use a model from ignitionrobotics.org in gazebo9?

Tags: gazebo-ignition, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to include in a gazebo9 world file a model that is available in  ignitionrobotics.org  using only the link generated in the website, is it possible?

Something like:

```
<include>
      <uri>
      https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/hatch
      </uri>
</include>
<include>
      <uri>
      https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Survivor Female
      </uri>
</include>
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
[Err] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:255] Unable to download model[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/hatch]
[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:464] File or path does not exist [""] [https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/hatch]
[Err] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:255] Unable to download model[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Survivor Female]
[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:464] File or path does not exist [""] [https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Survivor Female]
Error Code 11 Msg: Unable to find uri[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/hatch]
Error Code 10 Msg: Invalid uri[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/hatch]. Should be model://https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/hatch
Error Code 11 Msg: Unable to find uri[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Survivor Female]
Error Code 10 Msg: Invalid uri[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Survivor Female]. Should be model://https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Survivor Female
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25101/is-it-possible-to-directly-use-a-model-from-ignitionrobotics.org-in-gazebo9?/) by [rezenders](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26928/rezenders/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

If you check the dependencies of gazebo9 with `sudo apt-cache showpkg gazebo9`. There is no dependencies of ignition-fuel-tools. You will need to compile this from sources.

There is a tutorial [here](https://ignitionrobotics.org/tutorials/fuel_tools/1.0/md__data_ignition_ign-fuel-tools_tutorials_configuration.html) to download models with the command line:

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0